# c++ assign a int value to a struct? question about the constructor and operator overload

Tags: c++, struct, constructor, overloading, operator-keyword

I have a question in my project when I understand other people's code, I find a weird way that assigns an int value to a struct:

```
TestStruct ts = TestStruct(3004);
```

In the Teststruct, there's another substruct SS. SS only has one member which is an int type. (the original code, of course, is not like the one below).
I try to understand this in vs code on windows platform.
The code below is similar to the one of my project

My question is:

1. How is this possible? Assigning an int value to a struct (it's already worked in my project from other colleague's code).

> ---update: now I know the way used here is called conversion
>   constructor. int-->struct-->int, is that right?

2. How to understand the constructor overload and operator overload? I am confused by the following &, && and default thing... (in the source code, every struct has the following similar code:)

.

```
TestStruct() = default;
TestStruct(const TestStruct&) = default;
TestStruct& operator=(const TestStruct&) = default;
TestStruct(TestStruct&&) = default;
TestStruct& operator=(TestStruct&&) = default;
```

the test code is follows:

```
// 03_2 struct constructor.cpp 
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef struct subStruct {
    int si;
    subStruct(const int si_) : si(si_){   //compile error if no this constructor
    }
}SS;

struct TestStruct {
    SS  ss; 

    //constructor and operator overload
    TestStruct(const SS ss_)  : ss(ss_) {

    }

    TestStruct() = default;
    TestStruct(const TestStruct&) = default;
    TestStruct& operator=(const TestStruct&) = default;
    TestStruct(TestStruct&&) = default;
    TestStruct& operator=(TestStruct&&) = default;
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    TestStruct ts = TestStruct(3004);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. Are you unable to change `TestStruct` or `subStruct`? I feel `TestStruct` should take an `int` parameter, not an `SS`.

Comment: Consider `foo x = foo("abcd");`, isn't it odd that a string literal is assigned to some kind of other object? What if `foo` was a typedef for `std::string`, still odd?

Comment: @Tas, you can copy and run the code, it can work.
 now my understanding is:
first, in TestStruct(const SS ss_) constructor, int convert to a struct,
then in subStruct(const int si_)    constructor, struct convert to an int.
all this has been done automatically by conversion constructor.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, what's your definition of foo? I can't understanding what you mean

Answer (score 3):

> how is this possible? assign an int value to a struct

You provide a constructor for your `struct` that takes an `int`:

```
struct SS {
    int si;
    SS(int si) : si{ si } {}
};
```

So the `int` literal in

> ```
> TestStruct ts = TestStruct(3004);
> ```

can be converted to `SS` which is passed to your

> ```
> TestStruct(const SS ss_) : ss(ss_) {}
> ```

Comment: yes, I missed a constructor in the sub struct. how it works?

Comment: To make `TestStruct(const SS ss_)` work with an `int` a conversion from `int` to `SS` is required. `SS(int si)` provides this conversion.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, if the "structs" were aggregates, you could simply use brace initialization:

```
struct SS {                                 
    int si;                                 
};                                          

struct TestStruct {                         
    SS  ss;                                 
};                                          

int main()                                  
{                                           
    TestStruct ts = TestStruct{3004};       
}
```